# Making a game - What is the advantage of the secure variables?

Tags: c#, security, unity-game-engine, private

I have made Game in Unity , which contains lots of public and private varibles and          functions. I wanted the game to be secure , so I  bought Anti cheat toolkit from unity asset store  https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10395 .So my question is  do i need secured private variables ? If yes, then what is the use of private variables? What advantages do they have (in security terms) ?

Comment: Have you ever read the difference between a public and a private variable? Maybe even read a C# tutorial?

Comment: It's .... wild that this question has upvotes!  What a world.

Comment: If you need "security" on your game, you have to get the famous Anti-Cheat-Tool-Kit from the asset store. it's one of those things "everyone uses" - it's ubiquitous.  You can't have a game without security for preference obfuscation etc, and it would be totally pointless writing code yourself to do that.  Everyone just uses ACTK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> do I need to secure private variables ?

No, both public and private variables have the same security defences (or rather no security defences). If an attacker can view or modify a *public* variable, they can view or modify a *private* variable.

Access modifiers are there for programmer convenience and to help with architectural decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Private and public identifiers have nothing to do with security, but rather the visibility/accessibility of a method/variable/whatever.

A private var communicates to the developer that this variable is used only by its class and should not be touched/accessed anywhere else.

A public var communicates that the variable is accessed somewhere else and the value of the variable matters to the functionality to parts of the codebase/users

Answer (score 0):

Variable's state, either public, private or protected, only determines who can acces the information inside the variables, or who can do a certain action (for functions).
Also private variables can only be accesed by their containing class.

Comment: Not the one who downvoted, but I think the reason was that this statement: "Variable's state ... only determines who can acces the information inside the variables" is not technically correct. It's pretty easy to access/modify a private variable from a completely different class using reflection or debugger.

Answer (score 0):

public and private keywords only express what is "supposed" to be visible or not. In terms of security, it's always possible to call a private variable or method using reflection (for exemple) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming).